# Peer-to-Peer with Kubernetes Pods

Tags: .net, azure, kubernetes

I have n-amount of identical Kubernetes Pods that together are supposed to perform k-amount of tasks. One pod gets the REST request in telling it to do the k-amount of tasks. How can that pod tell the others what to do?

Just an example to make it a bit clearer: If I have 4 pod running and get a request with 20 tasks in, each pod should do 5 tasks. And for each scaling, or pod crash, that task number should be adapted as soon as possible.

Limitation: Kubernetes should be used because that's our system setup. The Kubernetes setup can't really be changed. I can't limit the replicas to just 1 (ArChItEcTuRe ReQuIrEmEnT), so I can't write it as a monolith. And because of that, I also can't write a master-slave setup (because I could have duplicate master-pods).

There are options where the different pods communicate through a table-storage/redis, but this seems very limited and slow (only one can write at a time, and every pod *needs* to write for keep-alive). Ideally when a request with, say, 1000 tasks comes in I want to have those tasks started instantly (ignoring potential need to start more pods to achieve those tasks).

The other option is using an Event Hub, but there individual pods can't be addresses each other directly, nor can I send an event to all.

All each pod needs to know is the amount of tasks requested (k), and the amount of running pods (n). In a normal peer-to-peer setup this would be easy, but as Kubernetes isn't intended for this kind of service behaviour it's seems impossible to create without a lot of hacking.

Is there some good way to set up some peed-to-peer communication between pods, other than misusing table-storage?

PS: The tasks are indefinitely running. They run until the task amount is set to 0 again. If a pod were to crash, another as to step in and pick up the tasks.

Comment: Is using the kubernetes Job resource an option? That already has all the behavior you need. Otherwise I don't see the issue with using redis as a task queue,just have every pod pull work from the queue until done. See Ruby's sidekiq utility or any other work queue.

Comment: What I may have forgotten to say is that those are indefinitely running tasks, the tasks run until the task count is set to 0 again. So just picking a task and working it off isn't an option. If a pod were to crash, another has to step in and pick up the crashed pods tasks.

Comment: I'd set this up with a queueing system like RabbitMQ; it's possible your application framework has some higher-level abstraction around this.  This is something that can be run locally without involving containers at all, which helps for development, and it cleanly handles the cases of there being no replicas (jobs back up in the queue and that's okay) and of tasks failing (RabbitMQ can retry them).